# Liferay died, how to repair?

Tags: tomcat, liferay

Suddenly i got this trying to view my liferay 6.1.1 tomcat 7.0.27 server:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getHomeURL(PortalUtil.java:605)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:114)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

What all this means and how to make my server work?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and only the web.xml file from the /webapps/ROOT folder was missing. Got the same file from backup and Liferay came back to life!

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly got the exact same error, on the same Liferay/Tomcat versions.

Check your deployed portlets. In my case, all the portlets, themes and ROOT in webapps folder, had their web.xml ERASED. I dont know the reason, maybe liferay did some of its magic. After I restored the erased web.xml-s from backup, everything started to work again.